# Embedding object to a linked list c++

Tags: c++, object, linked-list

I am trying to add on object to a linked list. The idea of my program is that to make a student information system. In this student information system when there will be a new entry of student then a new object of the class will be created and that object will be the information for a new node in the linked list. In other words the object will be the information field of the nodes of the linked list. I have tried this program but got  an error.

```
#include<iostream.h>
class result
{
    int age;
    char name[30];
    float marks;

public:
    void ret(int a, float m)
    {
        age = a;
        marks = m;

    }
};

struct node
{
    result info;
    struct node *next;
};


void main()
{
    struct node *h, *t;
    int g;
    float ma;
    cout<<"Enter age , name , marks\n";
    cin>>g;
    cin>>ma;
    result ob;
    h = NULL;
    t = new node;
    t->info = ob.ret(g,ma);
    t->next = NULL;
    h = t;
    cout<<t->info;
}
```

The error is:

1) Not an allowed type
2) Illegal structure operation

Comment: Where is the error occurring at?

Answer (score 0):

`ret` is a member of `result` that returns `void`. I am guessing you meant to make a constructor of `result` that takes two arguments. So, this is what you would do

```
class result
{
 int age;
 char name[30];
 float marks;

 public:
 result(){}
 result(int a, float m)
 {
  age = a;
  marks = m;

 }
};
```

And change `t->info = ob.ret(g,ma);` to `t->info = result(g, ma);`

Comment: @Padmini Please update your post with the code that has this change. Also provide the full compiler error output with this new code.

Comment: have changed the code as u said. But then also getting an error at cout<<t->info. The error is : Illegal structure operation.

Comment: You need to provide the overload for [`operator<<(result)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt).